# Reverse changes to int after DMA

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Say I have the following variable initialized within a class:

```
class testClass {
public:
    int someInt = 5;
};
```

and I want to add to or modify it using like this:

```
int main() {
    testClass *t = new testClass;
    cout << t->someInt << endl;
    t->someInt = 1;
    cout << t->someInt << endl;
    delete t;
    cout << t->someInt;
}
```

How can I revert the changes done by the `t->someInt` to `someInt` back to the initial declaration, of `int i = 5`?

Also, when I call delete before `cout << t->someInt` still exists. Why does the output of `t->someInt` still equals `1`? Shouldn't it have been deleted?

I am working on a game where it has present variables and I want to dynamically change the variables, such as a score, when the player gets a point to release memory and allow the player to replay the game after the variables are reverted back.

Comment: The last `cout << t->someInt;` invokes _undefined behavior_. Do not enter this land to make assumptions of how things work.

Comment: If you want to restore some value, you could just save a copy before changing it. Then just `t->someInt = savedInt;`. Also, there is no requirement that a deleted variable's value goes away *immediately*. But as you are not allowed to read it anyway, this doesn't really matter.

Comment: Resetting to the initial value can be performed with `*t = testClass()`. What you are trying to achieve is unclear. Maybe related to GoF's memento design pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I revert the changes done by the t->someInt to someInt back to
>   the initial declaration, of int i = 5?

You have to store a copy of the values you want to revert. You can either store just the int or a copy of the whole class.

For example, the following code stores the current value of `t` inside `t_backup`:

```
int main()
{
    testClass *t = new testClass;
    cout << t->someInt << endl;

    testClass *t_backup = new testClass(*t);

    t->someInt = 1;
    cout << t->someInt << endl;

    *t = *t_backup;
    cout << t->someInt << endl;

    delete t_backup;
    delete t;
}
```

Obviously, if your class is more complex, you will have to define your own copy constructor and assignation operator.

> Also, when I call delete before cout << t->someInt still exists. Why
>   does the output of t->someInt still equals 1? Shouldn't it have been
>   deleted?

After you call delete, any use of the variable is "undefined behaviour". It means that (almost) anything can happen. It can print a number or it can crash your computer.

Comment: Most of the time, what happens after a `delete` (even if it is undefined and can't be assessed) is that the memory is marked as available and that's all. This means that while the memory is not reused it can still be accessed and will have the same content as before deleting. However it's forbidden to delete it a second time, this is called a double free and will crash your application. This is why it's safer to set the pointer to `nullptr` after the `delete`. Notice that deleting a pointer which is null will do nothing (no crash).

Answer (score 0):

In order for "t" to not have a value, you have to set it to nullptr. (t = nullptr)

Comment: And if you do so, which is good practice, do not try to dereference it after !

Comment: I think you mean `t = nullptr;` (no asterisk).

Comment: True. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches.

The first and simplest is to just make a copy of the variable (or more than one). Based on what you've said, this is probably what you really want.

```
int input1 = 1;
char input2 = 'a';

while (play_game(input1, input2))
    ;
```

This repeatedly calls `play_game`, and each time it does, the two variables will start out with the prescribed values. `play_game` can modify its local copies of them as it sees fit, but as soon as it exits, those changes disappear.

If you really do get into a situation where you need to modify an object, and later return that object to its previous value, you might want to consider the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).